# How do I print an image in field collections (for custom theme)

Tags: 7, theming, media, entities

When I try and print an image in my custom field template using field collections module, I only get the word "array" instead of an image. This is Drupal 7 btw.

Following this great tutorial 
http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2013/06/03/better-way-theme-field-collections
I have added the following to my template.php file:

```
function rows_from_field_collection(&$vars, $field_name, $field_array) {
  $vars['rows'] = array();
  foreach($vars['element']['#items'] as $key => $item) {
  $entity_id = $item['value'];
  $entity = field_collection_item_load($entity_id);
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $entity);
  $row = array();
  foreach($field_array as $field){
  $row[$field] = $wrapper->$field->value();
}
$vars['rows'][] = $row;
```

}
 }

```
function TKC_preprocess_field(&$vars, $hook){

if ($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_roster') {
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'field__field_roster';

$field_array = array('field_athlete_full_name','field_roster_image');
rows_from_field_collection($vars, 'field_roster', $field_array);
 }
}
```

And then created a custom filed template in my theme file called field--field-roster.tpl.php

In this file, I have the following code - all of which works like a charm, excpet for the image filed which prints the word "array"

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
    <li>
        <?php print $row['field_roster_image']; ?>
        <p><?php print $row['field_athlete_full_name']; ?></p>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I think this is a basic issue and not sure how to change the line

```
<?php print $row['field_roster_image']; ?>
```

to make it render the image. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: try print render($row['field_roster_image'])

Comment: check the value of $row['field_roster_image'] by wrapping it in a print_r

Comment: Thanks for takign a look Andrew ! - I tried that, but it showed nothing. Nothing in the source code as well.

Comment: Does $rows have any values in it? If not you should check you are passing the vars correctly to the template

Comment: Andrew thanks again - yes there are. if you go down to "roster" on this page - all the team members' info is in $rows https://admissions.tkc.edu/athletics-sport/women%E2%80%99s-soccer

Just dbl checked and hI have the field title right - here is the line of code

Comment: <?php print render($row['field_roster_image']); ?>

Comment: Ah by using print_r I got the image array info to show

    <?php print_r($row['field_roster_image']); ?>